# How to find $ \displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{1+(\tan x)^e}dx $?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How to find $$\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{1+(\tan x)^e}dx $$Substitution seems not to work.

Comment: Enforce the substitution $x\to \pi/2-x$.

Comment: Note for close voters: The question linked has different parameters, but the accepted answer is general. Also just in case anyone is interested, I think this question originally comes from a putnam.

Comment: Ha, things become surprisingly easy after we do the right substitution and the $I+I$ trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$I= \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{1+(\tan x)^e}dx$$

$$= \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{1+(\tan (\frac{\pi}{2}-x))^e}dx$$

$$=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{(\tan(x))^e}{1+(\tan x)^e}dx$$

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks for your hint!